# str_replace_all doesn't replace any

Tags: r, string, replace

I am cleaning up some pdfs. The hope is to do minimal copy-pasting but I'm stuck on the first bit.  I can't believe there isn't a quicker version of Ctrl+H to replace all in R. What am I missing in this code?

```
c("17.23--$16.50--$19.68--$15.35--$15.64---$14.23--$17.29---$15.51---$17.8") %>% 
str_remove_all(pattern = "-") %>% 
  str_replace_all(pattern = "$", replacement = ",")

Current output: "17.23$16.50$19.68$15.35$15.64$14.23$17.29$15.51$17.8,"
Expected output: "17.23,16.50,19.68,15.35,15.64,14.23,17.29,15.51,17.8"
```

Ideally, the string would be cleaned up to produce a comma-separated string, but if there is also a way of skipping the comma-separation and transposing into a column of data with something like `separate_rows(sep = "$")` that would be great.

Comment: Some characters like `\^$.?*|+()[{` have special meaning in regex. You either need to escape them with 2 backslashes like `pattern = "\\$"` or (since you are using `stringr`) wrap that pattern in `fixed()` like `pattern = fixed("$")` which indicates that you are looking for a "fixed" pattern, not a pattern than uses regex variables. See the linked duplicate for more examples and explanation.

Comment: You could also use `*` as a "0 or more" quantifier and do your 2 lines in one step, `your_input |> str_replace_all(pattern = "-*\\$", replacement = ",")`. Or to turn it into a vector all at once `your_input |> stringr::str_split("-*\\$") |> unlist()`